# Original Lucas sequences primality test

Tags: reference-request

When I found in [Edouard Lucas' Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas) that he proved that $2^{127}-1$ is prime by hand, I wanted to see how did he do it. Unfortunately, every piece of information I find is about the Lucas-Lehmer test, that is a version of his test refined by Lehmer.

Since I wanted to do some comparisons about how many it would take to do so with a computer and a high-school multiplication algorithm (according to Wikipedia it took him $19$ years by hand) the Lucas-Lehmer test is not exactly what I am looking for. So, finally, where can I find the original test?

Comment: Do you have access to "Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization" by Riesel?

Comment: @Amzoti Uhhhm...yes...

Comment: @Amzoti I just found the *Primality tests of Lucasian type* part and it seems very interesting and promising. Thank you for pointing me to it.

Comment: You are very welcome, all of the original Lucas papers are available and the main one by Wagstaff (IIRC) is excellent. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant papers are:

- "Théorie des Fonctions Numériques Simplement Périodiques [I]," American Journal of Mathematics , Vol. 1, No. 2 (1878), pp. 184-196.  http://www.jstor.org/stable/2369308
- "Théorie des Fonctions Numériques Simplement Périodiques [II]," American Journal of Mathematics , Vol. 1, No. 4 (1878), pp. 289-321.  http://www.jstor.org/stable/2369373

Comment: Thank you for the references, but since I don't speak French it is a little hard to me to understand his paper. Not impossible, given the similarity with my native language, but a little painful. Is there an english version?

Comment: Not that I know of.